# Java Icon not working

Tags: java, swing, file-io, imageicon

So i have this code

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class pictest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Label Example");
    ImageIcon mine = new ImageIcon("‪C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/mine.jpg");
    JLabel pic = new JLabel(mine);
    frame.add(pic);
    frame.setSize(300,250);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JFrame framee = new JFrame("Label Example");
    ImageIcon minee = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/mine.jpg");
    JLabel pice = new JLabel(minee);
    framee.add(pice);
    framee.setSize(300,250);
    framee.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    framee.setVisible(true);

 }

}
```

So when i run the code i get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wwlj.jpg

(the left pic is the code from the top part, the right is the code from the bottom part)

As far as i can tell the code is exactly the same(except for variable names) and i can not figure out why the picture will not show up on the one on the left, is this a problem where i need to reinstall stuff, or is there something in the code that i am just getting wrong.
(also if someone could reformat this post to look right i would appreciate that, sorry i dont use stack overflow much but i was getting frustrated.)

Comment: `if someone could reformat this post` - all you need to do is edit your question and select the code and then click on the "{}" button.

Comment: Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); until you fix that, anything can happen.

Comment: It works fine for me. Mac OS X, Java 7. See what happens if you minimize the left window and restore it back. Does the image get loaded?

Comment: use double slashes to separate path, instead of `C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/mine.jpg` use `C://Users//Eric//Desktop//mine.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to save your code, I get the following error:

[image]

The image shows on the top frame only when I copy
 `ImageIcon minee = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/mine.jpg");`

and paste and edit it to

```
ImageIcon mine = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/mine.jpg");
```

I guess you are using some un-recognized charactes in that line.

Comment: I Thought this was what was causing this, but i wasn't sure, i initially copied the path from the properties page of the image, which must have contained the unrecognized text.  After typing out the path though it worked.  I tried to figure out which character was messed up but it must have been more than one because i could not narrow it down to one character.  Anyway thank you